# Leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code in my onCreate():

```
registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

This line seems to be throwing the following error: `Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`.

I just don't see how this is possible though - I completely uninstall my app and then install it again, and this is the only receiver registration in the entire app. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: did you unregister the receiver at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unregister your receiver in onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // Unregister since the activity is not visible
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
  super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Two points: the OP doesn't seem to be using LocalBroadcastManager, so should just use `Activity.unregisterReceiver(..)`; secondly (to the OP) it is good practise to register/unregister receivers in the matching pairs of methods in the Activity lifecycle (onCreate/onDestroy; onStart/onStop; or onResume/onPause).

Comment: I am doing this, but it doesn't seem to be resolving the issue.